# Table is too wide to fit on my page

Tags: tables, formatting

I created the following table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
 \caption{Descriptive statistics for the daily return of the timeseries.}         \label{tab:title}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll
                      S[table-format=-2.3]l
                      S[table-format=-2.3]l
                      S[table-format=-2.3]
                      S[table-format=3.3]
                      l[table-format=3.3]
                      *{9}{S[table-format=-2.3]}@{}
                      }
 \toprule
 & {Obs.} & {Mean} & {Std.Dev} & {Min} & {Max} & {Skewness} & {Kurtosis} & {Jarque Bera}\\
\hline
USDT & 1569 & 0.000 & 0.005 & -0.056 & 0.046 & 0.205 & 27.409 & 2.200e-16 \\ 
PAX & 706 & 0.000 & 0.010 & -0.108 & 0.118 & 1.040 & 65.617 & 2.200e-16\\
DGX & 813 & 0.001 & 0.045 & -0.349 & 0.564 & 2.626 & 44.129 & 2.200e-16\\
PAXG & 626 & 0.000 & 0.014 & -0.172 & 0.080 & -3.602 & 45.440 & 2.200e-16\\
DAI & 596 & 0.000 & 0.005 & -0.042 & 0.045 & 0.058 & 37.134 & 2.200e-16\\
WBTC & 405 & 0.007 & 0.097 & -0.356 & 0.370 & 0.475 & 2.301 & 2.200e-16\\
AMPL & 743 & 0.004 & 0.116 & -0.723 & 1.090 & 1.351 & 15.358 & 2.200e-16\\
BTC & 1657 & 0.003 & 0.043 & -0.389 & 0.264 & -0.162 & 6.484 & 2.200e-16\\
LTC & 928 & 0.003 & 0.057 & -0.381 & 0.296 & -0.080 & 7.069 & 2.200e-16\\
EUR & 1161 & 0.000 & 0.004 & -0.028 & 0.015 & -0.155 & 2.137 & 2.200e-16\\
JPY & 1161 & 0.000 & 0.004 & -0.026 & 0.022 & 0.001 & 2.865 & 2.200e-16\\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

Unfortunately it does not fit nicely on my page (it's a little too wide). I played around a lot but I can't seem to make it look ok. I have the same issue with another table... Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, for the most part it does. But I still have the problem that sometimes I have a rather large space between my columns and also the the \topline values are not in the center of the columns...

Also, it does not work for my Second table... I just edited my question and added the second table I have problems with.

Comment: There are several errors in the code you posted. The `siunitx`  and `booktabs` packages are missing in the preamble and `l[table-format=3.3]` should probably be `S[table-format=3.3]`. Fix these error before worrying about the "output". You also declare a total of 18 columns, but you only really use 9 of them. Also, the `table-format` options of some of your columns don't match their contents. Once corrected, your table should fit into the available space.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a corrected version of your table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\caption{Descriptive statistics for the daily return of the timeseries.}         \label{tab:title}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                      l
                      S[table-format=4]
                      S[table-format=1.3]
                      S[table-format=1.3]
                      S[table-format=-1.3]
                      S[table-format=1.3]
                      S[table-format=-1.3]
                      S[table-format=2.3]
                      S[table-format=1.3e-2]
                      @{}
                      }
\toprule
     & {Obs.} & {Mean} & {Std.Dev} & {Min} & {Max} & {Skewness} & {Kurtosis} & {Jarque Bera}\\
\midrule
USDT & 1569 & 0.000 & 0.005 & -0.056 & 0.046 & 0.205  & 27.409 & 2.200e-16 \\ 
PAX  & 706  & 0.000 & 0.010 & -0.108 & 0.118 & 1.040  & 65.617 & 2.200e-16\\
DGX  & 813  & 0.001 & 0.045 & -0.349 & 0.564 & 2.626  & 44.129 & 2.200e-16\\
PAXG & 626  & 0.000 & 0.014 & -0.172 & 0.080 & -3.602 & 45.440 & 2.200e-16\\
DAI  & 596  & 0.000 & 0.005 & -0.042 & 0.045 & 0.058  & 37.134 & 2.200e-16\\
WBTC & 405  & 0.007 & 0.097 & -0.356 & 0.370 & 0.475  & 2.301  & 2.200e-16\\
AMPL & 743  & 0.004 & 0.116 & -0.723 & 1.090 & 1.351  & 15.358 & 2.200e-16\\
BTC  & 1657 & 0.003 & 0.043 & -0.389 & 0.264 & -0.162 & 6.484  & 2.200e-16\\
LTC  & 928  & 0.003 & 0.057 & -0.381 & 0.296 & -0.080 & 7.069  & 2.200e-16\\
EUR  & 1161 & 0.000 & 0.004 & -0.028 & 0.015 & -0.155 & 2.137  & 2.200e-16\\
JPY  & 1161 & 0.000 & 0.004 & -0.026 & 0.022 & 0.001  & 2.865  & 2.200e-16\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```